# How switch between screen inside screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have to work inside two environment. One Windows (local) and one Linux (remote).
I've installed the screen linux utility in both.
I'm able to open a screen on my windows, then in one tab, I opened a ssh connection to the linux  remote and I start another screen.

Sample

```
linux  -- |0 linux remote 0| 1 linux remote 1 
windows-- |0 linux | 9 windows
```

I can switch between "linux remote 0" and "linux remote 1" using  Atl+.
This is configured in .screenrc (bindkey "^[0" select 0)
How could I switch to "9 windows"?

Answer (score 25):

Ah. screen-in-screen... very Inception. We need to go deeper...

That being said, you can send a ctrl-A to a nested screen by doing <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: Poetic and precise: what more can a humble developer ask for? ;)

Comment: I've found that issuing `Ctrl+A A` does only toggle between the current and last inner window within the inner screen session. How does one cycle through the entire inner screen window stack? Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, <kbd>9</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd> (that's a double-quote) and then select it from a list.

Comment: That's how to switch windows in a single `screen` session. The question is about nested screen sessions.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by [rocka84](https://superuser.com/users/189944/rocka84) but for the second command you don't need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> again. Like for creating a new screen in nested terminal you need to do like this <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

When I run screen in another screen, I use a different command character for each.

Rather than the default ctrl-A, I use ctrl-space (the null character, `escape ^@^@` in `.screenrc`) for the outer one, and ctrl-] (`escape ^]^]` in `.screenrc`) for the inner one.

If you don't do that, you can send a single command character to the inner nested `screen` session (or to any other command running under `screen`) by doubling it.

Comment: How can I change the command character in `.screenrc` depending on the current depth?

Comment: @Scz: I don't know. I have a screen session running on my home system (with `escape ^@^@`) and another session running on another system (with `escape ^]^]`). I just happen to have an `ssh` to the second system as one of the windows on the first.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, you can send <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> to the inner screen with <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>. Just do this twice to switch the inner screen.
Make sure to release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for the second (and forth) <kbd>A</kbd>

Btw: This goes for all control sequences of the inner screen, just hit <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> before all Keys and drop the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for sequence keys. Easier to show than to describe:
<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> creates a new inner screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, followed by  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>'(single quote)'</kbd> and choose the screen you want.

Or you can jus hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a(double tap)</kbd> to return to previous screen.

Answer (score 1):

Marc B's answer seemed to work, except it only juggled between the current and last window in the inner screen session. The following did allow to have the *commonly expected* behavior of `Ctrl+A` inside the contained session...

`Ctrl+A A`

And for example, when cycling through the windows...

`Ctrl+A A [N,P]`

Answer (score 0):

You may use like below

- for next screen and

> Ctrl + A n

for previous screen

> Ctrl + A  p